# File read() function in Unix Systems

Tags: c, file, unix

The code below restarts the `read()` function if it fails due to interruption by signal. The `read()` resumes its reading from where it was interrupted. So if `read()` is interrupted just before reading `EOF` character, what will it return that how many bytes it read?

```
int r_read(int fd, void *buf, int size)
{
   while((retval=read(fd,buf,size))==-1 && errno ==EINTR);
   return retval;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: There is no such thing as an `EOF` character.

Answer (score 3):

This is why the number of bytes read should be kept as a total, to avoid interrupt issues. It's also useful for non-blocking I/O.

```
{
    int ret = 0, nread;
    char *nbuf = (char *) buf;

    while ((nread = read(fd, nbuf, size)) != 0)
    {
        if (nread > 0)
            ret += nread, nbuf += nread, size -= nread;
        elif (errno != EINTR)
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `errno == EINTR`, it means that `read` was interrupted before it could read any data at all according to the `man` page. I.e. from my reading, it is as if a `read` with status `EINTR` just didn't happen as far as the data in the stream is concerned. So it seems as if you can simply retry without worrying about having lost any bytes. I find this a bit surprising, and I haven't actually tested it, but that is what the manual says.

Here is the actual text from the man page:

> EINTR  The  call  was interrupted by a signal before any data was read; see signal(7).

Edit: I tested this now, and I found that if I interrupted the read, `EINTR` would only be returned if the read was interrupted before anything had been read. Otherwise, it would return successfully, having read less than the requested number of bytes. So to get the number of bytes you want, you will need something that restarts, as the other answer indicates.

Comment: The same as I am thinking but my text book doesn't mentions it and the function I made to return how many bytes it read are the total sum, as mentioned by Brette Hale.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "EOF character" as such, there is the end-of-file condition which is indicated as a read of 0 bytes. The EINTR error is set only if `read` is interrupted while waiting for something to happen, i.e. *before* the underlying resource produces any data.

Since EOF normally causes `read` to stop waiting and return a value, `read` cannot be interrupted doing that, and if it does, it will just return what it has—the EOF indicator. If `read` is interrupted while *waiting* for EOF (before it is announced by the underlying resource), it will of course return -1 and set EINTR.

Comment: Suppose the read() function has read 10 bytes of data and stored in buffer.Now if the read() function in unix is interrupted by signal and I restart the read function as shown above, where will be the next byte be stored in the buffer, either currentposition+1 or will be written from the start of the buffer.

Comment: @UmerFarooq If `read` is interrupted after reading ten bytes, it will return 10, and so will your function. `errno` will remain unchanged.