# Behavior Read() when interrupted in Unix

Tags: c, file, unix, file-handling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [File read() function in Unix Systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218477/file-read-function-in-unix-systems)

Suppose the read() function has read 10 bytes of data and stored in buffer.Now if the read() function in unix is interrupted by signal and I restart the read function as shown below, where will be the next byte be stored in the buffer, either currentposition+1 or will be written from the start of the buffer.

```
int r_read(int fd, void *buf, int size)
{
   while((retval=read(fd,buf,size))==-1 && errno ==EINTR);
  return retval;
}
```

Regards

Comment: Why do you post the same question again?

Comment: KingsIndian How can be this a duplicate when the gener of the problem is different in both the questions. Please read carefully before saying duplicate

Comment: Why are you [asking the same thing twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218477/file-read-function-in-unix-systems)?

Answer (score 0):

As you have coded, after getting `EINTR` it will call `read` again, with `buf` as starting address of memory to store data. This looks appropriate.

However, `read` may return with positive number when it has read partial data, in that case your `while()` is break.